# BiBTeX Name: First/last order

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

My reference look like this (example):

[image]

I would like the names ordered as follow:

Holler, J. N. & C. D. Koller (2011)

Furthermore I would like my editors listed as: First Last, First Last et al.

I use a (modified form of) `apalike` as my bibliography style.

Comment: I have also edited in mine, but do you know how to change the order?

Answer (score 2):

Grafting the changes you're requesting, i.e., changing the sorting orders for authors and editors, onto an existing copy of `apalike.bst` is likely going to be tricky, to put it politely.

I'd therefore like to suggest that you run the `makebst` utility. The file `makebst.tex` should be included in all modern TeX distributions; run the utility by typing `latex makebst` at a command line prompt. This interactive utility program will provide a detailed set of questions and various possible answer options for each question. Choose the options you need. In most (but not all) cases, the default option (indicated by an asterisk) will be what you want anyway.

Among the more important questions for which you wouldn't want the default option are:

- Q.3, "Name of the final OUTPUT .bst file?" (choose a filename that appeals to you);
- Q.9, "STYLE OF CITATIONS" (be sure to choose option "a", for author-year style citations); and
- Q.17 (or so), "AUTHOR NAMES" (choose option "a").

At the very end, the utility will ask you

```
Shall I now run this batch job?
```

Answer "yes" and a custom `.bst` file (with the filename you chose at the prompt following Question 3) will be created.

As a side-benefit of creating your own custom bst file using the `makebst` method, you'll get a bibliography style that "knows" what to do with fields such as `url`, `doi`, `isbn`, and `issn`. The original `apalike` style is more than twenty years old; a the time, fields such as `url` and `doi` simply weren't meaningful...

Once you have the custom `.bst` file, it shouldn't be too difficult for you to replicate any earlier changes you may have applied to your copy of `apalike.bst`.